# Rotating a camera feed in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, camera, actionscript, feed

I am trying to rotate a live camera feed 90 degrees so it's the correct orientation. Here is what I have so far but it just won't do anything with the rotation.

```html
      public function setupCamera(param1:int, param2:int) : void
      {
         camera = Camera.getCamera("1");
         camera.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,camStatusHandler);
         camera.setMode(param1,param2,stage.frameRate);
         video = new Video(param1,param2);
         video.scaleX = -1;
       video.rotation = 90;
         video.x = video_placement.x + video_placement.width;
         video.y = video_placement.y;
         video.attachCamera(camera);
         addChildAt(video,0);
      }
```

Comment: That should work, but you'll have to adjust your position to compensate for the scale and rotation (which is probably making it go offscreen)

Comment: "Won't do anything with the rotation..." so nothing happens at all? No error? No video? No nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the rotation is working.    The problem is when you rotate 90 degrees the registration/anchor point is now effectively the top-right corner (so if it's at position 0,0 the video will appear off-screen making it look like it's not working).

You can compensate by adding the width of the video to it's position:

```
video.x = video.width + video_placement.x;
```

In the same manner, setting the scale to -1 inverts the registration point, and since you've rotated the object you need to compensate for it on the y plane by adding the height of the video to it's position:

```
video.y = video.height + video_placement.y;
```